# Xcode won't open a swift file in project, the file icon is grayed (lower alpha), after downloading clone from remote

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Thanks to losing last MacBook, had to download a project from remote by cloning.  After opening the project, all the files seem to be listed no problem.  One problem, the modelController file (with all the networking, the most important file) won't show contents when selected.  When you click on the file it doesn't show on the view screen, and you get an audible negatory sound that MacOS produces when you've clicked on the unclickable.

When going back to GitHub, however, the modelController shows all its code no problem.  It's just when you open the Xcode project it won't let you touch the files contents.  You can see some stuff in the identity inspector for it like "Name: PlayerFetcherController.swift" but in the view screen where the code would, it displays whichever file you were viewing last.  There's no error listed anywhere, the only indication that something is wrong is a grayed-down file icon (vs the brighter icons for the other files which ALL work fine).

Downloading/cloning old projects from Github has been a real nightmare. There's gotta be a better way than GitHub, it really is awful experience from start to finish.

[image]

Comment: Locate the file in the project folder and import it to the project manually.

Comment: Submit feedback to Apple, it's a usability bug and should provide more context instead of just beeping at you. https://feedbackassistant.apple.com

Answer (score 2):

It's easy to forget to add files that were linked in an Xcode project on Github.

If you're not careful about "Copying" files into your project, or moving them around you can cause issues with Github. Always make sure you Copy Files to a Xcode project when adding them externally, or use the "Add files to ..." dialog in Xcode.

**Test your code**

I always recommend testing your respository by cloning it after you set it up, and periodically afterwards if you're the sole developer. If you have multiple Macs, you can test by cloning and pull changes to verify it works (I sometimes do this in a VM to test old macOS versions).

If you're on a team, these types of issues will be caught by teammates.

**Learn from your mistakes**

Unfortunately Xcode makes it very easy to accidentally screw up a project, and so does git. As you get more experience you learn to avoid these pitfalls. Learning takes time, and the struggle is necessary to progress forward.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this by right-clicking on the containing folder and choose `Add files to "Folder Name"`. And then from the file selector opened select the file and click `Add` button with your target selected and it'll work fine.